# Get data without page reload in angular5

Tags: angular

I want to show updated data without page reload. I used Observables but not working . Can anyone please help. I tried like this

My ts File

```
cat_update() {
    let data= {
      id: this.catdata[0]._id,
      category_name:this.category_name
    }

    this.accountService.updatecategory(data).subscribe(response => {
      alert("successfully updated")
    }, err => {
      alert("Something went wrong while update");
    })
}
```

My service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataService } from './data.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AccountService {
  public apiPath: string;

  constructor(ds: DataService, public http: HttpClient) {
    this.apiPath = ds.apiPath;
   }
   public dt(res:Response){
    return res;
  }

  updatecategory(data): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(this.apiPath + 'user/updatecategory', 
      data)
    .pipe(map(this.dt)));
  }
```

My html File

```
<div class="form-group">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="category_name">
   <br>
   <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="cat_fun()" *ngIf="tmp==0 else notmp">Add</button>
   <ng-template #notmp>
      <button class="btn btn-success" (click)="cat_update()" class="btn btn-warning">Update</button>
   </ng-template>
</div>
```

In my html just i wrote a method for updating and adding category section. updating and adding to database is fine. But i need updated data without page reload.

Comment: share you component.html file also

Comment: I updated my html file in above please check.

Comment: try adding type="button" to your button html. I had a problem at one time where not having this was causing the whole form to be submitted

Comment: I tried type="button" ----------Not working

Comment: what do you mean you want updated data without page reload? Angular app doesn't  reload page. If you mean that you want to show updated data without firing another request to fetch data then you simply have to update the object when you get an OK response for your update request.